# When are the C tp_as_mapping (et al.) methods invoked?

Tags: python, python-c-api, python-extensions

The C PyObject structure contains the fields `tp_as_number`, `tp_as_sequence` and `tp_as_mapping`. In which circumstances are these invoked? Can anybody provide some example Python code which would result in these C methods being called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those methods are the equivalent of python's [special methods](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#specialnames), and are called in the same circumstances. For example `tp_as_number->nb_add` is called when executing `a + b` and `a` is the extension type.
It is the equivalent of `__add__`. The `inplace_*` functions are the equivalents of `__i*__` methods.

Note that the `__r*__` methods are implemented simply swapping arguments to the normal functions, thus `5 + a` where `a` is an extension type will first try to call the numeric version of `nb_add`, after this failed it tries `nb_add` of `a` putting `5` as first argument and `a` as the second one.

The same is true for the `tp_as_mapping` and `tp_as_sequence` structs. The `mp_length` and `sq_length` functions are called by the built-in function `len`, and are the equivalent of `__len__`. Theoretically you could implement different functions for `mp_length` and `sq_length`, in which case the `sq_length` has precedence(this can be seen from the source code, even though I don't know whether this behaviour is documented).

Also note that, for example, the `+` operator can be implemented in different functions. The `sq_concat` is called after trying `nb_add`, and thus an extension type can support `+` operator without having an `nb_add` function set.

Comment: Many thanks. Would appreciate if you could point me to some further doc, if there is any...

Comment: @isedev You can find some documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/objimpl.html). You can also find some information in the [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/extending/newtypes.html#abstract-protocol-support)